# set environment variable `ANDROID_NDK_HOME`

Tags: android, maven, android-ndk

I am using macbook. I have downloaded [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html) & extracted it to

```
~/mytool/android-ndk-r10e
```

In **.bash_profile** I have set :

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME = ~/mytool/android-ndk-r10e
```

My project pom.xml contains the following plugin:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.0</version>
   <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```

When I run `mvn clean install`, I got the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.simpligility.maven.plugins:android-maven-plugin:4.3.0:ndk-build (default-ndk-build) on project MyTrackor: No Android NDK path could be found. 

You may configure it in the pom using <ndk><path>...</path></ndk> or <properties><ndk.path>...</ndk.path></properties> or on command-line using -Dandroid.ndk.path=... or by setting environment variable ANDROID_NDK_HOME -> [Help 1]
```

The above error complains that no Android NDK path could be found, and it suggests me to set environment variable `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` to resolve the problem.

But as you see in my **.bash_profile**, I have already set the envrionment variable `ANDROID_NDK_HOME`. Why I still get this error ?

Comment: Did you reload your `bash_profile`? Try to force it and execute the export command inside a terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using line command to verify all exported variables

```
export
```

if you do no see ANDROID_NDK_HOME, that means you bash file has not been reloaded. then

```
source .bash_profile to reload the config.
```

else you see ANDROID_NDK_HOME, it may be another problem.

Comment: Thanks, I run `export`, output shows me `declare -x ANDROID_NDK_HOME` , there is no value in ANDROID_NDK_HOME. When I run `source .bash_profile `, I got `-bash: export: ~/mytool/android-ndk-r10e: not a valid identifier`. why is that?

Comment: It's probably the spaces on either side of the equals sign: `export ANDROID_NDK_HOME = ~/mytool/android-ndk-r10e`